# PlantUML in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, plantuml

[image]Is there any documentation explaining how to use PlantUML in real Visual Studio 2022 (not VSCode). There is a PlantUML extension, but no documentation how to use is.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vincent-Dagpin.PlantUMLEditor

Comment: Please share the link to the extension

Comment: Have you seen the link to the product url https://plantuml.com/?

Answer (score 0):

After giving the file the right extension, it worked.

Didn't see that it is only .mdpuml. In VSCode there were different file extensions.

However only website states only 2000 installations. Maybe it is not good, but that was not the question.